# change detection issue with angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

## Detail

I am trying to implement ng2-select in form there are issue it is not detecting changing in angular by it self. I try to run my required asycn task with `zone.run()` nnow the issue is that is show the data in ng2-select when I trigger reset or submit form. otherwise it shows undefined value in inut feild and not shows any response in ng2-select

### before

[image]

#### after trigger

[image]

## html

```html
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- Reg-Form -->
        <form id="sky-form4" class="sky-form" (ngSubmit)="Submit(userEdit)" #userEdit="ngForm">
            <header>Edit User Account</header>

            <fieldset>
                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="First Name" required [value]="fname">
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Enter First Name</b>
                    </label>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Last Name" [value]="lname">
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Enter Last Name</b>
                    </label>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" [value]="email">
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Enter Email Address</b>
                    </label>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <label>
                        Roles
                    </label>
                    <div *ngIf="roles.length > 0">
                        <ng-select [initData]="initRoleData"
                                   [multiple]="true"
                                   [items]="roles"
                                   (data)="refreshValue($event)"
                                   (selected)="selected($event)"
                                   (removed)="removed($event)"
                                   placeholder="No roles assign">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
                <section>
                    <label>
                        Groups
                    </label>
                    <div *ngIf="groups.length > 0">
                        <ng-select [initData]="initGroupData"
                                   [multiple]="true"
                                   [items]="groups"
                                   (data)="refreshValue($event)"
                                   (selected)="selected($event)"
                                   (removed)="removed($event)"
                                   placeholder="No groups assign">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </fieldset>
            <footer>
                <button type="reset" class="btn-u">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-u" [disabled]="!userEdit.form.valid">Save</button>
            </footer>
        </form>
        <!-- End Reg-Form -->
    </div>

</div><!--/end row-->
```

### Ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'users-edit',
    templateUrl: '../../app/components/user/user-edit.html',
    directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {
    private isAdmin: Boolean = false;
    private _data: Observable<any[]>;
    private fname: string;
    private id: number;
    private lname: string;
    private email: string;
    private _roles: Observable<any[]>;
    public roles: any = [];
    public groups: any = [];
    private initRoleData: Array<any>[] = [];
    private initGroupData: Array<any>[] = [];


    public selected(value: any): void {
        console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
    }

    public removed(value: any): void {
        console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
    }

    public refreshValue(value: any): void {
        this.initRoleData = value;
    }


    constructor(private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private _ngZone: NgZone,
        private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.isCurrentUserAdmin();
            this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
                this.id = +params['id'];
            });
        });
    }

    private isCurrentUserAdmin() {
        this.userService.isCurrentUserAdmin(this.authService.getUserName())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.isAdmin = Boolean(data);
            },
            error => {
                console.log("error while retriving admin");
                console.log(error);
                this.userService.handleError(error);
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.userService.getUser(this.id)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.fname = data.FirstName;
                    this.lname = data.LastName;
                    this.email = data.Email;
                });
            this.getUserGroupByIdFunc();

            this.getUserRoleByIdFunc();

            this.userService.getAllRoles()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    data.forEach(role => {
                        this.roles.push(role.Name);
                        this.ref.detectChanges();
                    });
                });

            this.userService.getAllGroups()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    data.forEach(group => {
                        this.groups.push(group.Name);
                        this.ref.detectChanges();
                    });
                });
        });
        this.ref.markForCheck();
    }

    getUserRoleByIdFunc() {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.userService.getUserRolesById(this.id)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    data.forEach(role => {
                        this.initRoleData.push(role.Name);
                        this.ref.detectChanges();
                    });
                });
        });
    }


    getUserGroupByIdFunc() {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.userService.getUserGroupsById(this.id)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    data.forEach(group => {
                        this.initGroupData.push(group.Name);
                        this.ref.detectChanges();
                    });
                });
        });
    }

    Submit(form: any) {
        alert(form);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using changeDetection OnPush in Angular 2/4/5. Please use the following:

1. `array = [...array,...element];` instead of `array = array.push(element);`
   This will trigger the change detection by pushing the item into an array.
2. this.ref.markForCheck(); inside every subscription.

This will make the changeDetection working into your case.

link for reference: [https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/](http://Understanding%20Change%20Detection%20Strategy%20in%20Angular)

Here is the updated .ts for your component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'users-edit',
    templateUrl: '../../app/components/user/user-edit.html',
    directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class UserEditComponent implements OnInit {
    private isAdmin: Boolean = false;
    private _data: Observable<any[]>;
    private fname: string;
    private id: number;
    private lname: string;
    private email: string;
    private _roles: Observable<any[]>;
    public roles: any = [];
    public groups: any = [];
    private initRoleData: Array<any>[] = [];
    private initGroupData: Array<any>[] = [];


    public selected(value: any): void {
        console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
    }

    public removed(value: any): void {
        console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
    }

    public refreshValue(value: any): void {
        this.initRoleData = value;
    }


    constructor(private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private _ngZone: NgZone,
        private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.isCurrentUserAdmin();
            this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
                this.id = +params['id'];
                this.ref.markForCheck();
            });
        });
    }

    private isCurrentUserAdmin() {
        this.userService.isCurrentUserAdmin(this.authService.getUserName())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.isAdmin = Boolean(data);
                this.ref.markForCheck();
            },
            error => {
                console.log("error while retriving admin");
                console.log(error);
                this.userService.handleError(error);
                this.ref.markForCheck();
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.userService.getUser(this.id)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.fname = data.FirstName;
                    this.lname = data.LastName;
                    this.email = data.Email;
                    this.ref.markForCheck();
                });
            this.getUserGroupByIdFunc();

            this.getUserRoleByIdFunc();

            this.userService.getAllRoles()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    data.forEach(role => {
                        this.roles = [...this.roles,...role.Name];
                    });
                    this.ref.markForCheck();
                });

            this.userService.getAllGroups()
                .subscribe(data => {
                    data.forEach(group => {
                        this.groups = [...this.groups,...group.Name];
                    });
                    this.ref.markForCheck();
                });
            this.ref.markForCheck();
        });

    }

    getUserRoleByIdFunc() {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.userService.getUserRolesById(this.id)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    data.forEach(role => {
                        this.initRoleData = [...this.initRoleData,...role.Name];
                    });
                    this.ref.markForCheck();
                });
        });
    }


    getUserGroupByIdFunc() {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.userService.getUserGroupsById(this.id)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    data.forEach(group => {
                        this.initGroupData = [...this.initGroupData,...group.Name];
                    });
                    this.ref.markForCheck();
                });
        });
    }

    Submit(form: any) {
        alert(form);

    }

}
```